# ¿Cómo crear un link dinámico de Mercado Pago en PHP?

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy terminando mi website de desarrollador web y he llegado a la sección donde el cliente puede pagar por el website que ha solicitado. Encontré cómo ofrecer Mercado Pago en mi website, pero el generador del botón de pago no es dinámico sino que se debe ingresar el importe a pagar al crear dicho botón. Mi intención es que el monto a pagar y otras variables vengan de la base de datos pero no tengo idea de cómo implementarlo. Leí un poco sobre el SDK de Mercado Pago pero no logré implementarlo. Lo instalé con Composer pero no se cómo llamarlo ni cómo usarlo. Cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar es mas que bienvenida!

Edit: pongo el código que aparece en [[https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/reference/payments/_payments/post]](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/reference/payments/_payments/post)

```
    <?php

  MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");

  $payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();

  $payment->transaction_amount = 100;
  $payment->token = "ff8080814c11e237014c1ff593b57b4d";
  $payment->installments = 1;
  $payment->payer = array(
        "type" => "customer",
        "id" => "123456789-jxOV430go9fx2e"
    );

  $payment->save();

?>
```

Creo que le falta un Require 'archivo de MP a incluir, donde están las clases y demás' pero lo que instalé con Composer no tiene .php que se pueda incluir
Y ¿no necesito agregar "USE x" antes de "MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");"?

Disculpen, pero soy novato en esto del desarrollo web.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Entiendo. Ahí edito el post para ponerle el código que me está generando problemas para entenderlo.

Comment: ok lo que intentas hacer implementa un recurso externo del cual, personalmente no tengo conocimiento; si alguien lo tiene a lo mejor te puede ayudar de momento, te invito a que veas la documentacion de mercado pago ... estoy casi seguro de que deben tener ejemplos de como incorporar sus SDK en php. saludos.